# SQL - count over partition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Please, tell me what is wrong with this:

```
 select 
 p.date,
 (SELECT COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID_code)
 FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
 WHERE p.end_volume_KN <> 0
 AND p.date                = '31-OCT-16'
 AND (p.local_grade_MB IS NULL OR p.local_grade_MB ='0' OR          p.local_grade_MB ='N')) AS ERROR_CNT
 FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
 where p.date                = '31-OCT-16';
```

Over partition part is problem, without it, it works.

> Error details:
>   ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

Comment: For one, you have an `Oracle` error message, but you tagged your question as both `MySQL` and `SQL Server`.

Comment: by partitioning you will get more then one result. While in your select, it may only be a single value. You could join the subquery instead of adding it to your SELECT

Comment: Why do you have a subquery at all here? Also `date` is a reserved word and not a valid column name; and `31-OCT-16' is a string not a date. Life is easier if you use the right data types. Having one column that stores 'N' and '0' looks odd too.

Comment: @Ema As an aside, what datatype is `p.date`? If it's DATE, then you should not be comparing dates to strings. I.e. change `p.date = '31-OCT-16'` to `p.date = to_date('31/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. That way, you're not relying on the nls_date_format parameter to govern the implicit conversion. Especially as if that changed, your code would most likely fail.

Comment: Partitioning by a column you aren't showing is also a bit odd. Are you sure you want an analytic count, not an aggregate? Can you edit the question to include the table structure, some sample data and the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually after is a conditional count - something like:

```
select   p.dt,
         count(case when p.end_volume_kn != 0
                         and (p.local_grade_mb is null
                              or p.local_grade_mb in ('0', 'N'))
                         then 1
               end) error_cnt
FROM     POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
where    p.dt = to_date('31/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by p.dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, something like this (not tested):

```
select 
 p.date,
 t.val AS ERROR_CNT    

 FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
 JOIN (SELECT p.ID_code, COUNT (*) as val  OVER (PARTITION BY p2.ID_code)
 FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p2
 WHERE p2.end_volume_KN <> 0
 AND p2.date                = '31-OCT-16'
 AND (p2.local_grade_MB IS NULL OR p2.local_grade_MB ='0' 
     OR  p.local_grade_MB ='N')) as t ON t.ID_Code = p.ID_code
 where p.date                = '31-OCT-16';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
 select 
 p.date,
 (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT p.id_code
 FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
 WHERE p.end_volume_KN <> 0
AND p.date                = '31-OCT-16'
AND (p.local_grade_MB IS NULL OR p.local_grade_MB ='0' OR              p.local_grade_MB ='N'))) AS ERROR_CNT
FROM POOL_AREA.F_volume_GCOA p
 where p.date                = '31-OCT-16';
```